# I have an array that I want to grab some values from and add them as a object to a inititalValues in a Ant Design Form Componenet

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, antd

I have a Ant Design Form Component that takes some initital vales. I need to populate them from an array, but I it needs to be in this format.

```
 <Form
    {...layout}
    name="basic"
    initialValues={{ "name-0": "fdsanfdsk", "name-1": "fdsafjasf9" }} // I need the name values 
                                                                      // from the array here
    onFinish={onFinish}
    onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
  >
```

My array looks like so

```
[{
    "__typename": "FormInputVal",
    "name": "name",
    "_id": "291541872966369805",
    "type": "text"
}, {
    "__typename": "FormInputVal",
    "name": "name",
    "_id": "291541888089981453",
    "type": "text"
}, {
    "__typename": "FormInputVal",
    "name": "test",
    "_id": "291644307943719437",
    "type": "text"
}, {
    "__typename": "FormInputVal",
    "name": "test",
    "_id": "291649317517656585",
    "type": "text"
}, {
    "__typename": "FormInputVal",
    "name": "test",
    "_id": "291649666387280392",
    "type": "text"
}, {
    "__typename": "FormInputVal",
    "name": "test",
    "_id": "291651264892109325",
    "type": "text"
}, {
    "__typename": "FormInputVal",
    "name": "test",
    "_id": "291651422325309961",
    "type": "text"
}, {
    "__typename": "FormInputVal",
    "name": "test",
    "_id": "291651568083665417",
    "type": "text"
}, {
    "__typename": "FormInputVal",
    "name": "test",
    "_id": "291653619769410057",
    "type": "text"
}]
```

I just need the names from the array, and inserted into the initalValues object in the Form Component, with a -0, -1, -2 tacked on.

I have tried the following

```
const test = formState?.map((item, idx) => {
      return `${item.name}-${idx}:"fdsjfs"`;
    });
```

and then I end up with another array, and I have tried turning that array test into a Object with `Object.assign({},test)` but then it has keys on it.

Any help would be greatley appreciated

Comment: `Object.fromEntries(formState.map((o,id)=>[`${o.name}-${id}`, o.name]))` you can take fromEntries

Comment: You need this as output : `{ "name-0": "name", "name-1": "name" }` ? right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using the `reduce` method.

```
const test = formState.reduce((obj, item, idx) => {
  return { ...obj, [`${item.name}-${idx}`]: 'fdsjfs' };
}, {});
```